# Как добавить столбец с порядковым номером записи сгруппировав по заданному столбцу?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть таблица с полями: `id_клиента, id_заказа, инфо_заказа, дата`. Есть DataFrame, который пишет в CSV. Необходимо в DataFrame добавить столбец, в котором будут содержаться порядковые номера заказов каждого клиента.

Пример DataFrame:

```
frame=pd.read_sql
frame=pd.read_sql("select * from orders where orderinfo not like '%[T%]%' ", 
connection);
df = pd.DataFrame(frame);
df.to_csv('D:/database/test1.csv', sep=';', index=0, line_terminator='\n', 
quotechar='"');
```

Данные в таблице (это фрагмент, их порядка 600 тыс.):

```
orderid         clientid
4250037527175   458697677354
4250037527223   458697654011
4250037527287   458697677354
4250037527332   458697654011
4250037527445   458697654011
4250037527578   458697645413
4250037527616   458697645413
4250037527976   458697677354
```

В результате должно выйти нечто подобное:

```
serial orderid         clientid
1      4250037527175   458697677354
1      4250037527223   458697654011
2      4250037527287   458697677354
2      4250037527332   458697654011
3      4250037527445   458697654011
1      4250037527578   458697645413
2      4250037527616   458697645413
3      4250037527976   458697677354
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести в вопросе пример желаемого результата?

Comment: Пример желаемого результата добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [GroupBy.cumcount()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['serial'] = df.groupby('clientid').cumcount() + 1
```

---

результат:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
         orderid      clientid  serial
0  4250037527175  458697677354       1
1  4250037527223  458697654011       1
2  4250037527287  458697677354       2
3  4250037527332  458697654011       2
4  4250037527445  458697654011       3
5  4250037527578  458697645413       1
6  4250037527616  458697645413       2
7  4250037527976  458697677354       3
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало на ура!